# Ignore updates for ClickOnce App if user does not have the option

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a WPF Application, it is being deployed via ClickOnce deployment.

My pricing strategy was basically: you get updates and you pay a minimal annual fee.

This application is distributed to a few hundred clients, and some of them now want the option to disable updates, hence, buy the package and that's it. Other clients want to be able to receive updates for a year, or until the next major build.

Using ClickOnce I was able to always push updates to clients, however, I now neeed to be able to turn off updates for ceratain clients based on their license key.

Is there any way one can include the logic on a ClickOnce installation?

... lastly.... can one speicify to only update within the current major release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of using auto-updates, you should manually check for updates inside your application, and based on the license, major version etc, take certain actions: [How to: Check for Application Updates Programmatically Using the ClickOnce Deployment API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx)